# Disabling echo in java

Tags: java, echo

I am trying to mask the password by disabling echo but it is not working....

By masking I mean to output *** instead of the password itself....

And i looked into the `readPassword` function of console but it just disables echo.

And i am a beginner so plz describe in detail...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
//import java.nio.charset.Charset;
//import sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder;
//import sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder;
/*class output1 extends OutputStream
{
public void write(int b)
{

}
}
class input1 extends InputStream
{

}*/

class testi
{
static native boolean echo(boolean on) throws IOException;
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//PrintStream out1;
System.out.println("Enter a line: ");
try {
            //cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            //out1=new PrintStream(OutputStream out);
            int c;
            while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
                //out1.write((int)('*'));
                echo(false);
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            echo(true);
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        /*if (out1 != null) {
            out1.close();
        }*/
    }
}
}
```

This is to be run in a console(cmd)..

Thanx in advance... :)

P.S i am too bad at programming

Answer (score 2):

Though this may not solve the answer to the way you are looking, but how about hiding the input all together? Take a look at the link below:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/console_readpassword.htm

Comment: Ya i already mentioned that i have already looked into it but its nt wat i want to do.....
No offence bt i don't think that it is not possible..... 
btw thanx... :)

Comment: Looking at the javadoc for readpassword; there is some parameters that you could help; you  public char[] readPassword(String fmt, Object... args) Edit: Here is the link to javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you may use `JOptionPane` with `JPasswordField`, even if you run your app in console.

Here is example from http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/03/java-password-dialog.html

```
final JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField();

JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane(jpf, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog("Password:");
dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jpf.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
    }
});
dialog.setVisible(true);
int result = (Integer) jop.getValue();
dialog.dispose();
char[] password = null;
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    password = jpf.getPassword();
}
if (password != null)
    System.out.println("your password: " + new String(password));
```